# Problems with currfiledir, pgfplotsstable and compilation from a section file

Tags: pgfplotstable, standalone, external-files, csv, currfile

## My project

#### File tree

```
- section
  - mysection.tex
- tools
  - mystandalone_data.csv
  - mystandalone.tex
main.tex
```

### MWE

`main.tex`

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[mode=buildmissing]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz,pgfplots,pgfplotstable}
\pgfplotsset{width=7cm,compat=1.18}
\usepackage{currfile}

\begin{document}
\input{sections/mysection}
\end{document}
```

`mysection.tex`

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[mode=buildmissing]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz,pgfplots,pgfplotstable}
\pgfplotsset{width=7cm,compat=1.18}

\usepackage{currfile}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \includestandalone{tools/mystandalone}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

`mystandalone.tex`

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz,pgfplots,pgfplotstable}
\pgfplotsset{width=7cm,compat=1.18}
\usepackage{currfile}


\edef\CurrentFileDir{\currfiledir}% 
\pgfplotstableread[col sep = semicolon,header=true]{\CurrentFileDir mystandalone_data.csv}\mydata


  \begin{document}
      \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[table/col sep=semicolon]
            \addplot table [x=Oui,y expr=\coordindex]{\mydata};
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

`mystandalone_data.csv`

```
Oui;Non
45;45
21;23
23;45
24;48
30;45
40;48
```

## My problem

When I compile:

- from `mystandalone.tex`, it works
- from `main.tex`, it works
- from `mysection.tex` it throws me the following error

```
Package standalone Warning: Graphic 'tools/mystandalone.pdf' could not be build.
Shell escape activated? on input line 12.

(/compile/tools/mystandalone.tex
! Undefined control sequence.
\pgfplotstableread@filename ->\mydata 
                                      
l.15 ...table [x=Oui,y expr=\coordindex]{\mydata};
```

## What I've tried

For now, I've tried:

- expanding `currfiledir` with `\edef\CurrentFileDir{\currfiledir}`
- using/expanding `currfileabsdir`.

None of this solutions worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `standalone` package redefines the `\documentclass` macro so that all content before `\begin{document}` in sub-files is ignored.

The definition of `\mydata` macro

```tex
\pgfplotstableread[col sep = semicolon,header=true]{\CurrentFileDir mystandalone_data.csv}\mydata
```

is not read when you compile from another file than `mystandalone.tex`. Move it between `\begin{document}` and `\end{document}`.

```tex
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz,pgfplots,pgfplotstable}
\pgfplotsset{width=7cm,compat=1.18}
\usepackage{currfile}

\begin{document}
  \pgfplotstableread[col sep = semicolon,header=true]{\currfiledir mystandalone_data.csv}\mydata
    \begin{tikzpicture}
      \begin{axis}[table/col sep=semicolon]
          \addplot table [x=Oui,y expr=\coordindex]{\mydata};
      \end{axis}
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Do you have any idea about why compiling from `main.tex` used to work with the `pgfplotstableread` outside the `document` environment?

Comment: @Enevevet As I remember, I couldn't compile your code from `main.tex`. Are you sure you  didn't compile it from `mystandalone.tex` before testing from `main.tex` ? Otherwise the `standalone` package uses the pdf output without regenerate it (with `mode=buildmissing`).

I realise that I didn't try to compile from `mysection.tex`, as I was looking to make it work from `main.tex`. It still fails from `mysection.tex` because latex can't find `tools/mystandalone` (the root is then the `section` directory). A workaround would be to create a symbolic link (on linux, for example, `ln -s ../tools`).